# Does order of boolean statements make a performance difference in a MySQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

Suppose I want to query a table based on multiple WHERE clauses.

Would either of these statements be faster than the other?

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table 
   WHERE (line_type='section_intro' OR line_type='question') 
     AND (line_order BETWEEN 0 AND 12) 
ORDER BY line_order";
```

...or:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table 
   WHERE (line_order BETWEEN 0 AND 12) 
     AND (line_type='section_intro' OR line_type='question') 
ORDER BY line_order;
```

I guess what it would come down to is whether the first one would select more than 12 records, and then pare down from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the order does not matter. Query optimizer is going to estimate all conditions separately and decide on the best order based on what indexes are applicable / size of targeted selection / etc...

Comment: Excellent, that's what I kind of thought but figured it would be good to know for future reference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your indexes.  If you have a multi- index on (line_type, line_order), the first query is faster.  If you have an index on (line_order, line_type), the second one is faster.  This is because for multi-column primary keys, MySQL can only do the comparisons in order.  Otherwise, there is no difference.

Comment: This is incorrect. Both queries are going to be exactly the same on either index; which one of the **indexes** will make queries perform faster depends on how many matching rows are in the table / index. For example, if all (or vast majority) of rows in the table have `line_type` set to either `section_intro` or `question`, index defined on (line_type, line_order) would not be used at all.